# Dragonlance - Why did Laurana fall for Kitiara's Trap?

Tags: dragonlance

In [*Dragons of Spring Dawning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_of_Spring_Dawning), Kitiara's message to Laurana was obviously a trap.  It contained no proof Tanis had actually been wounded, and it required Laurana to place herself in an extremely vulnerable position (come without any real guards, to a meeting place of Kitiara's choosing while bringing along a sociopath who hates Laurana.)

Laurana knew Kitiara was evil and had powerful motives to want to capture or kill her (both because Laurana was the commander of the army opposing Kitiara,  and because Laurana was Kitiara's romantic rival), and up to that point Laurana had been shown to be a highly intelligent woman. She even had her friends Flint Fireforge and Tasslehoff Burrfoot tell her Kitiara could not be trusted and the message was obviously a trap.

However, she still falls for it completely, refusing to even consider that the message could be a trap.  So why did Laurana fall for Kitiara's trap?  What made her believe she could trust Kitiara?

Comment: Perhaps she couldn't take the risk that it was true, that Tanis was injured, and not go to see him.

Comment: Right, it's one of those situations where even an intelligent person is forced to blunder into a trap because they have no other choice from their point of view.

Comment: I wouldn't say she "fell" for the trap. She knew going in it was a trap.

Answer (score 12):

**In-universe answer:**
The letter Kitiara passed with a draconian was a carefully crafted mixture of lies and half-truths.

<sup>From "Dragons of Spring Dawning" Book 2 Chapter 2</sup>

> ... Laurana nodded, wordlessly, staring at her hands in her lap.
>
> ‘I never told you,’ she murmured in a voice barely audible, ‘I couldn’t . . . I kept hoping . . . Kitiara said . . .
> said she’d left Tanis in—some place called Flotsam . . . to look after things while she was gone.’
>
> ‘Liar!’ said Tas promptly.
>
> ‘No.’ Laurana shook her head. ‘When she says we are two women who understand each other, she’s
> right. She wasn’t lying. She was telling the truth, I know. And at the Tower she **mentioned the dream**.’

This is the only true thing in that talk. The rest was a mixture of Kitiara's whims and taunts. Tanis was forced to play along with her, risking that his friends could be discovered, and escaped at the first opportunity.

> Laurana lifted her head. ‘Do you remember the dream?’
>
> Flint nodded uncomfortably. Tasslehoff shuffled his feet.
>
> ‘Only Tanis could have told her about the dream we all shared,’ Laurana continued, swallowing a
> choking feeling in her throat. ‘I saw him with her in the dream, just as I saw Sturm’s death. The dream’s
> coming true . . .’

Laurana is seeing her worst fears come to life. As Raistlin has warned, not all things shown in the dream were true.

> Laurana was quiet a moment, then, ‘I’m going. I’ll
> exchange Bakaris.’
>
> Flint heaved a sigh. He had seen this coming.
>
> ‘Laurana—’
>
> ‘Wait a minute, Flint,’ she interrupted. ‘If Tanis received a message saying you were dying, what would
> he do?’
>
> ‘That’s not the point,’ Flint mumbled.
>
> ‘If he had to go into the Abyss itself, past a thousand dragons, he’d come to you—’

Laurana chooses to come after Tanis, ignoring the dangers involved and putting everything at risk. Her love for Tanis is clearly more important for her than everything else. She chooses even to ignore that Kitiara's message is a deception.

**Out-of-universe answer:** my favourite quote from *"Sword Of Truth"* book series by Terry Goodkind:

> People are stupid; given proper motivation almost anyone will believe almost anything. Because people are stupid, they will believe a lie because they want to believe it's true, or because they are afraid it might be true

Laurana believes a lie because she is afraid it may be true. Even smart people can be deceived by such manipulations; a woman in love is especially vulnerable.

Comment: I'd add another upvote just for quoting the First Wizard Rule.

Answer (score 3):

I’ll defend Laurana’s decision to trust Kitiara which really wasn’t unreasonable on the information available to her at the time.

As for Kitiara’s message not containing any proof that Tanis was with her, in a world that lacks video or photographic technology, it’s hard to see how Kitiara’s note could have contained any such proof (it’s not like Kitiara could have included a photograph of Tanis with today’s newspaper to prove that she had him), so Laurana would have no reason to expect such proof or to be suspicious by its absence.  And of course Laurana did have very strong evidence that Tanis was with Kitiara both from her conversation with Kitiara at the High Clerist’s Tower where Kitiara knew things that only a very small number of people (Tanis included) could have told her, and from Gilthanas informing her how he had overheard Kitiara bragging about how Tanis was serving her while he was in Sanction.  (Kitiara had no way of knowing Gilthanas was eavesdropping on her there and thus no reason to be lying.)  Thus it was hardly unreasonable for Laurana to believe that Tanis was with Kitiara.  (Indeed on the information available to her it would have been irrational for her to believe otherwise.)

As for Kitiara requiring Laurana to come in person and with barely any guards, that isn’t inherently suspicious as commanders meeting in person with the enemy with few or no guards present was a common practice in ancient/medieval warfare.  Hannibal Barca and Scipio Africanus met in person with each only having a single bodyguard present prior to the Battle of Zama, and they are considered two of the greatest generals of all time.  Likewise during the Sicilian War, Augustus Caesar (the political genius who would go on to found the Roman Empire) went onboard the ship of his enemy Sextus Pompey to negotiate with him in person.  Thus in being willing to meet with her enemy in person with few body guards present, Laurana was in good company as she was acting no different than some of the greatest military and political leaders of all time.

Laurana also had good reason to believe she could trust Kitiara based on their prior encounter at the High Clerist’s Tower.  Remember during that prior encounter Kitiara had caught Laurana in an extremely vulnerable position (alone, unarmed, and so exhausted from using the Dragon Orb that she was struggling just to keep standing) and could have easily killed or captured Laurana.  (At one point she literally had a Dragonlance pointed right at the unarmed Laurana’s chest.) And it’s not like Kitiara didn’t have strong motive to want to harm Laurana there either.  Yes, Laurana was not yet the Golden General, but she was still Kitiara’s (extremely beautiful) romantic rival and had already done great damage to the Dragonarmies with her having already killed a Dragon Highlord, crippled Kitiara’s second-in-command Bakaris, and successfully used the Dragon Orb to rout the Blue Dragonarmy from the High Clerist’s Tower.  (Some might argue that Kitiara didn’t know at that point that it was Laurana who had used the Dragon Orb, but given that Kitiara had witnessed Laurana taunt the attacking dragons and then run into the tower after which just mere moments later a strange magical light came from the tower and Kitiara’s army fell apart, after which Laurana emerged from the tower looking half-dead, it doesn’t seem like it would be that difficult for Kitiara to put two and two together and figure out that it was Laurana that unleashed the magical attack on Kitiara’s forces there.)  Yet even with Kitiara having strong motive and the perfect opportunity to harm Laurana at the High Clerist’s Tower, Kitiara made no effort to (physically) harm Laurana during that encounter.  It would thus be perfectly logical for Laurana to conclude from that prior encounter that if Kitiara wanted to harm her then she would have done so at the High Clerist’s Tower, and that therefore Kitiara must genuinely not want to harm her (probably out of respect for Tanis), and that therefore she can trust Kitiara to honor a truce.

As for Laurana disregarding Flint and Tasslehoff’s advice, while Flint and Tasslehoff did warn her that the message was a trap, neither of them (despite knowing Kitiara personally) gave Laurana any specific examples of Kitiara personally acting in a dishonorable manner.    If they had given Laurana specific examples from their personal history with Kitiara of her acting dishonorably then Laurana might well have listened to them, but in the absence of such specifics it’s understandable that Laurana chose to rely instead on her own prior experience with Kitiara which was of Kitiara acting as an enemy but a honorable enemy (e.g. her showing respect for the fallen Sturm and not attacking Laurana when she was defenseless.)

It must also be remembered that by this point in the story Laurana has had a lot of experience with her male friends being rather overprotective towards her. Tanis and Gilthanas didn’t want her joining the quest at all, none of them wanted her accompanying the attack on Icewall Castle, Gunthar and Sturm didn’t want her to stay at the High Clerist’s Tower, and Tasslehoff didn’t want her to risk using the Dragon Orb.  Furthermore, every time she’s gone against her friend's overprotectiveness she’s been proven right with her not only surviving but succeeding brilliantly.  Given that history it’s understandable that she would think that Flint and Tasslehoff were just being overprotective here and decide to trust in her own judgment, since so far she’s been proven right every time she did that.

Thus while Laurana may have made a mistake in trusting Kitiara, it was not an unreasonable mistake.